# Writing to an array text file

Tags: php, arrays

So i want to write to a txt file using php. This txt file containts values for a array. The problem is that when i write in my textfield array[0] gets longer in stead of adding a new line in the array(array[1]). i tried and searched for 3 hours but cant find anything!

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="arraytest2.php">
  nieuwe regel <input type="text" method = "GET" name="nregel"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php


$file = "./members.txt";
$members = array();

if(isset($_GET['nregel']))
{
    $nregel = $_GET['nregel'];
    file_put_contents($file,$nregel,FILE_APPEND);


}

$members[] = file_get_contents($file);
var_dump($members);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with `$members = explode("\n",file_get_contents($file));`

Comment: @D.Kasipovic: Or just `$members = file($file);`.

Comment: True that, well said.

Comment: ^its not working the string keeps getting longer but dont add a array[1] just making the string longer

Answer (score 1):

Try add '\n' before the string that you should save...

Something like:

```
file_put_contents($file, "\n{$nregel}", FILE_APPEND);
```

And to read like array you'll need to split all file into array...
Try something like:

```
preg_split('/\n/', file_get_contents(...));
```

Remember... you have more then half path here...

Answer (score 0):

edit the following line

```
file_put_contents($file,$nregel,FILE_APPEND);
```

to read

```
file_put_contents($file,$nregel."\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your value every time by appending any delimiter. Delimiter must not be the part of data.

Here I am taking '|' as delimiter

so code to write the file would be

```
file_put_contents($file, '|'.$nregel, FILE_APPEND);
```

and to retrieve

```
$members[] = explode('|', file_get_contents($file));
```